# Why can't I get a message dialog to show at end?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I can't seem to get the message dialog to show at the end. The program runs with no errors, asks for input and then nothing as if it is ignoring my if statement. Any clue?

```
input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Internet package choice(A,B, or C):");

hours=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of hours used:");
rate=Integer.parseInt(hours);

  if(input.equals(a)){

     if(rate>10){
        optionA=(rate-10) * 2.00 +9.95;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The total is $ " + optionA);}

     else if(rate<=10){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The total is $ " + 9.95);
```

Everything is initialized and declared so I'm stumped on this.

Comment: Could it be that input does not equal a? Note that even if a and input are both strings, uppercase and lowercase letters are not the same.

Comment: input doesn't equal a. It's also no use to put else if (rate <= 10 ). this is exactly the same as just putting: else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*input.equals(a)* must be returning false. Step thru it in the debugger and see

Comment: I figured it out i needed to change a char to a string value and instead of a input.equals to a input.equalsIgnoreCase, sorry for not posting the whole code as it would have been easier to solve the problem.